# Continuity, partial derivatives, differentiability questions for $f(x, y):= \frac{x^2 \sin y^2}{x^2+y^4}$

Tags: analysis, derivatives, solution-verification, continuity, partial-derivative

I would like to know if you think my answers are correct, I am not so sure about $1$ and $3$ and I don't know how to answer $4$.

> Define $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by
> \begin{align*}
> f(x, y):= \frac{x^2 \sin y^2}{x^2+y^4}, & (x, y) \neq(0,0) & \\ f(x,y) := 0, & (x, y)=(0,0)
> \end{align*}
>
> 1. Is the function continuous in (0,0)?
> 2. Do the partial derivatives $(D_1f)(0,0)$ en $(D_2f)(0,0)$ exist?
> 3. For which $u \in \mathbb{R}^2 \backslash \{0\}$ does the directional derivative $(D_uf)(0,0)$ exist?
> 4. Is $f$ differentiable in $(0,0)$?
> 5. Is $f$ a $C^1$ function?

1. To show that $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$, we need to show that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)=f(0,0)=0$. We can do this by using the epsilon-delta definition of a limit. To do this, we need to show that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that if $||(x,y) - (0,0)|| < \delta$, then $|f(x,y) - f(0,0)| < \epsilon$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and take $\delta = \sqrt{\epsilon}$. If $||(x,y) - (0,0)|| < \delta$, then we have:
\begin{align*}
|f(x,y) - f(0,0)| &= ||\frac{x^2\sin y^2}{x^2+y^4} - 0|| \
&= |\frac{x^2\sin y^2}{x^2+y^4}| \
& \leq |\frac{x^2\sin y^2}{x^2}| \
& \leq |\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2}| = y^2 \
& \leq x^2 + y^2 = \delta^2 = \epsilon.
\end{align*}

Here, we used that $x^2 \leq x^2 + y^4$, since $y^4 \geq 0$ for all $y$ and observed that $0 \leq |\sin y^2| \leq 1$ for all $y$. Thus, the limit of the function exists at 0 and $f$ is continuous at 0.

2. We prove this using the definition of partial derivative. We have $(D_jf)(a) := \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(a + te_j) - f(a)}{t}$ with $a = (0 \quad 0)^T$. Thus:
   \begin{align*}
   (D_1f)(0,0) & = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f\left(\left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \ 0 \ \end{array}\right) + t\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \ 0 \ \end{array}\right)\right) - 0}{t} \
   & = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(t,0) - 0}{t} \
   & = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\frac{t^2\sin(0^2)}{t^2 + 0^4} - 0}{t} \
   & = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\frac{t^2 \cdot 0}{t^2}}{t}\
   & = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{0}{t^3} \
   & = \lim_{t \to 0} 0 \
   & = 0
   \end{align*}
   and
   \begin{align*}
   (D_2f)(0,0) & = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f\left(\left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \ 0 \ \end{array}\right) + t\left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \ 1 \ \end{array}\right)\right) - 0}{t} \
   & = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(0,t) - 0}{t} \
   & = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\frac{0^2\sin(t^2)}{0^2 + t^4} - 0}{t}\
   & = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\frac{0}{t^4}}{t}\
   & = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{0}{t^5} \
   & = \lim_{t \to 0} 0 \
   & = 0.
   \end{align*}
   So the partial derivatives $(D_1f)(0,0)$ and $(D_2f)(0,0)$ exist.
3. We look at the definition of the directional derivative $(D_uf)(0,0) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(a + tu) - f(a)}{t}$. For $a = (0 \quad 0)^T$, this gives (with $u := (u_1, u_2)$):
   \begin{align*}
   \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(a + tu) - f(a)}{t} &= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(tu)}{t} \
   & = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(t(u_1, u_2))}{t} \
   &= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(tu_1, tu_2)}{t} \
   & = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\frac{t^2u_1^2 \cdot \sin(t^2u_2^2)}{t^2u_1^2 + t^4u_2^4}}{t} \
   & = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t^2u_1^2 \cdot \sin(t^2u_2^2)}{t^3u_1^2 + t^5u_2^4} \
   & = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{u_1^2\sin(t^2u_2^2)}{tu_1^2 + t^3u_2^4}\
   & = \frac{u_1^2\sin(0^2 u_2^2)}{0u_1^2 + 0^3u_2^4} \
   & = \frac{0}{0}.
   \end{align*}
   So for no $u \in \mathbb{R}^2 \backslash {0}$, the directional derivative $(D_uf)(0,0)$ exists.
4. We use the theorem that says when $f$ is differentiable in $a$, then the partial derivatives $(D_jf_i)(a)$ exist and we have the total derivative $Df(a)$. ??
5. To show that $f$ is a $C^1$ function, we need to show that the partial derivatives exist and are continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

The partial derivatives of $f$ are:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) &= \frac{2x\sin y^2 (x^2+y^4) - x^2\sin y^2 \cdot 2x}{(x^2+y^4)^2} \
&= \frac{2x\sin y^2 (y^4)}{(x^2+y^4)^2}, \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) &= \frac{x^2 \cdot 2y\cos y^2 (x^2+y^4) - x^2\sin y^2 \cdot 4y^3}{(x^2+y^4)^2} \
\end{align*}
Both partial derivatives are continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$ since they are defined as quotients of continuous functions with denominators that do not become zero. Therefore, $f$ is a $C^1$ function on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: There is an issue with 1st question, you essentially wrote $1\le \epsilon$... Instead use $|\sin y^2|\le y^2$ Also I don't know what editor you copy/pasted from but it's hard to read.

Comment: So then we get 
\begin{align*}
|f(x,y) - f(0,0)| &= ||\frac{x^2\sin y^2}{x^2+y^4} - 0|| \\
&= |\frac{x^2\sin y^2}{x^2+y^4}| \\
& \leq |\frac{x^2\sin y^2}{x^2}| \\
& \leq |\frac{x^2 y^2}{x^2}|  \\
& = y^2 \\
& \leq \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} 
& = ||(x,y)|| < \delta = \epsilon.
\end{align*}

But I don't think I can conclude $ y^2 \leq \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ right? Do you know what I should do instead? @zwim

Comment: But maybe I can say $y^2 \leq x^2 + y^2 = \delta^2 = \epsilon$? When I choose $\epsilon = \delta^2$

Comment: 3. is $\frac00$ then you said exists?

Comment: You can use $|y|<1\implies y^2\le |y|\le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ without the need to change epsilon, just take $\delta=\min(1,\epsilon)$ which is a classic.

Comment: @BobDobbs So it doesn't exist for all $u$?

Comment: @zwim i changed it is this possible?

Comment: @Allison Is it same as 4? I mean 3.

Comment: @BobDobbs I don't understand?

Comment: I think it is not $C^1$ function. Yesterday I saw so.  Today I am writing.

Comment: Why its not C1? Can you explain? @BobDobbs

Answer (score 1):

The third part.

$$(D_uf)(0,0)=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{tu_1^2}{u_1^2+t^2u_2^2}\frac{\sin(t^2u_2^2)}{t^2}=0. u_2^2=0.$$

The fourth part. I am not sure about the solution yet. WolframAlpha confused me. It says "SlowLarge".

By using the definition
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (x_0,y_0)}\frac{f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)-D_1(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)-D_2(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)}{\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}}$$
of differentiablity for functions of two variables and letting $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2\sin y^2}{x^2+y^4}$ and $(x_0,y_0)=(0,0)$, the origin, we get
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{x^2\sin y^2}{(x^2+y^4)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}.$$
Due to Maclaurin series of sine function it is enough to consider
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^4)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}.$$
By passing to polar coordinates with $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$, $r>0$, we obtain the limit
$$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{r\sin^2\theta}{1+r^2\sin^2\theta\tan^2\theta}=0$$
where $\theta=\theta(r).$ So the function is differentiable at the origin.

The fifth part. Although $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=0$, the limit
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{2xy^4\sin y^2}{(x^2+y^4)^2}$$
does not exist. So, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is not continuous and $f$ is not a $C^1$-function. To show the non-existence of the limit above, choose the path $x=y^2$. Then, the limit along this path is $\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin y^2}{2y^2}=\frac12\neq 0.$

Comment: Thank you for answering the question by its definition, I did not think about that yet! Do you think the other questions are alright? How about 3?

Comment: I googled for the definition. Partial derivatives are enough for me.